# Python matplotlib Bar plot works for D freq but not for T

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, bar-chart

I have a very simple example which works well if freq='D', but does not if freq='T'.

The example bellow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

periods = 10

data = [x for x in range(periods)]
data[4:7] = np.nan, np.nan, np.nan
idx = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01 00:00:00', periods = periods, freq='T')

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = idx, columns=['value'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.bar(df.index, df['value'])

plt.show()
time.sleep(5)
```

returns the following picture:

[image]

Changing frequency to D,

```
idx = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01 00:00:00', periods = periods, freq='D')
```

produces a good graph.

[image]

What is the problem with the first graph?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the width of the bars (is too wide).
Try:

```
ax.bar(df.index, df['value'], width=1/24/60/2)
```

You may also want to adjust the tick label formatter, e.g.:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%T'))
```

Comment: Your solution works nicely. Thank you very much.
If I want to have bars next to each other I believe that width should be 1/24/60, and for 8H 1/3. 
I will use edgecolor property to provide visual boundary.
Thank you very veru much again. Best regards.

Comment: Is there a way to set color dynamically?
For example, if the value is below 5, then color = blue, otherwise color = red.

Comment: yes, the color property also takes arrays: `color_mask = ['red' if v < 5 else 'blue' for v in df['value'].values]` and subsequently `ax.bar(df.index, df['value'], width=1/24/60/1, color=color_mask)`